# Plot time series and image in R so that x axis labels line up perfectly

Tags: image, r, plot

I am trying to plot a time series (a seismograph) with a corresponding spectrogram in R.
Since I would like to compare the time series with the spectrogram, the X axis labels on the time series need to line up with the X axis labels on the spectrogram.  However, I'm having a lot of trouble with this.  The best I've been able to do so far is use

```
par(mar=c(0,10,0,8))
```

and try to manually force the spectrogram labels to line up with the time series labels by tweaking the spectrogram margin.  Of course this is only approximate and they still do not line up perfectly.  Is there a way to make the axes generated by the code below match up with each other?

```
par(mfcol=c(2,1))
plot(seq_len(1000)*0.01, sin(2*pi*seq_len(1000)*0.01), type="l",xlab="Time",
ylab="Amplitude", main="Time Series", xlim=c(1,10))
image(seq_len(1000)*0.01,seq_len(100)*0.1,array(runif(1000000),dim=c(1000,100)),
xlab="Time", ylab="Frequency", main="Spectrogram", xlim=c(1,10))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `rasterImage` ?  It takes four arguments to set the corners of the image into the currently defined plot space (based on the existing x and y scales).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
par(mfcol=c(2,1))
plot(seq_len(1000)*0.01, sin(2*pi*seq_len(1000)*0.01), type="l", xaxs="i")
image(seq_len(1000)*0.01,seq_len(100)*0.1,array(runif(1000000),dim=c(1000,100)),
    xlab="Time", ylab="Frequency", main="Spectrogram")
```

Just drop the xlim= arguments and use xaxs="i" in the plot() function  to match the default for image().

Answer (score 2):

You can either add `xaxs='i'` to the call to `plot` (this removes the extra padding so it lines up with the image plot), or you could use `par('usr')` after the 1st plot to see what the x limits are and use those values in the `xlim` call in image.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is way easier than it looked initially.  The secret is to make a "dummy plot" and then add the image to the plot.  So here's how the new, working code looks:

```
par(mfcol=c(2,1))
plot(seq_len(1000)*0.01, sin(2*pi*seq_len(1000)*0.01),
type="l",xlab="Time",ylab="Amplitude", main="Time Series")
plot(c(0,10), c(0,10), type="n") #Dummy plot with axis limits for our spectrogram
image(seq_len(1000)*0.01,seq_len(100)*0.1,array(runif(1000000),dim=c(1000,100)),
xlab="Time", ylab="Frequency", main="Spectrogram",add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Good to know that works with `image` as well as `rasterImage` per my previous comment!

Answer (score 0):

Similar, but conversely, to Greg Snow's answer, you could add `xaxs='r'` to the call to `image` as follows:

```
par(mar=c(0,10,0,8))
par(mfcol=c(2,1))
plot(seq_len(1000)*0.01, sin(2*pi*seq_len(1000)*0.01), type="l",xlab="Time",
     ylab="Amplitude", main="Time Series", xlim=c(1,10))
image(seq_len(1000)*0.01,seq_len(100)*0.1,array(runif(1000000),dim=c(1000,100)),
      xlab="Time", ylab="Frequency", main="Spectrogram", xlim=c(1,10), xaxs="r")
```

Don't forget to save your par() setting first.

(maybe I should have put that above)